# Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6 on Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, installation, osx-snow-leopard

I am looking to get started on iOS 6 development. I had developed on iOS 4 way back and I have Xcode 4.2 running on my machine right now. I also have some projects on there from previous iOS versions.

I would like to download the latest developer version Xcode 4.5 + iOS 6 and start developing on my system however, I dont want to lose the previous projects that I have written. I would like to be able to compile them and run them in the simulator.

I have the following questions:

- Can I install and run Xcode 4.5 on Snow Leopard?
- Once I install Xcode 4.5 will that upgrade my existing Xcode installation?
- If my existing Xcode installation is overridden to Xcode 4.5 will I be able to run my apps from iOS 3+ and iOS 4+ on the new Xcode?
- If Xcode 4.5 installs as a separate installation on my Mac can I run both Xcode versions together? What are the best practices for that installation?

Comment: iOS 6 is under NDA. You can not discuss this topic outside the apple developer forums. That being said, Xcode beta wont replace your current installation of Xcode

Comment: Your question says Snow Leopard but it is tagged [osx-mountain-lion]. So which version are you running?

Comment: Ops Im running snow leopard. Ill change the tag

Comment: @banditKing It's already been changed.

Comment: Why can't you just upgrade to Lion or Mountain Lion? Most applications have support now for both.

Comment: @J2theC OK I understand. I thought I was OK because I wasn't discussing any features or anything about XCode 4.5 or iOS6. I only wanted to know whther they can exist together with the previous XCode versions.

Comment: Yes I wanted to check whether there was a way other than upgrading and spending $$. I gues I WILL have to upgrade :( and spend $$

Comment: Mountain Lion and Lion is very cheap compared to previous Mac OS X versions and Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't talk about Xcode 4.5 because of the NDA but I can answer some of your questions based on Xcode 4.3 and 4.4.

---

- Can I install and run Xcode 4.5 on Snow Leopard?

No. Xcode 4.2 is the last supported version on Snow Leopard

- Once I install Xcode 4.5 will that upgrade my existing Xcode installation?

Even though you can't upgrade on Snow Leopard, on Lion Xcode 4.3+ installs besides Xcode 4.0-4.2 with the move of the `Developer` folder to inside Xcode.app.

- If my existing Xcode installation is overridden to Xcode 4.5 will I be able to run my apps from iOS 3+ and iOS 4+ on the new Xcode?

Can't really say about Xcode 4.5 but on 4.4 you would be able to get the iOS 5 simulators with 4.3 available to download manually through the Xcode's preferences window on Lion but you can only use the iOS 5 simulators on Mountain Lion. You can however test for iOS 3+ on a real device.

- If Xcode 4.5 installs as a separate installation on my Mac can I run both Xcode versions together? What are the best practices for that installation?

You would have to be under Lion in this case with both Xcode 4.2 and 4.5 installed. There should be no problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

"Xcode 4.2 is the last supported version on Snow Leopard." - Glad I found this.

For some reason the Xcode 4.2 Snow Leopard Image is not available via the iOS Developer Portal. It is offered for Lion, but the latest version for Snow Leopard available is 3.2.5.

However it is available via the Mac Developer Portal, as I found here:
[image]

Ridiculous, but most likely mix up on their part.