# Running iPhone 5 Simulator on Snow Leopard

Tags: ios-simulator, osx-snow-leopard, iphone-5

I am running the iOS6 SDK on my mac running Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard using steps from this [Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

I'm now trying to get the iPhone 4" screen to work. I have been able to get iOS 6 to show up in the iOS simulator under the Hardware > Version menu. When I try to load an iOS 6 device, I get the error: *"The simulated application quit" - "Click Relaunch to try again".* It then gives me an option to switch to a different SDK. If I choose iOS6, it again crashes. If I choose iOS 5, it loads correctly.

I also don't have an iPhone 4" screen option under the Hardware > Device menu.

I have copied the `iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk` folder from the Xcode Disk Image to my computer.

I'm not able to upgrade my computer past Snow Leopard.

---

So I need to be able to:

1. load iOS 6 in the iOS Simulator
2. load an iPhone 4" in the simulator

Comment: If you are serious about iOS development then it's probably time to get a a Mac which is new enough to run Mountain Lion. Pretty much any Mac made in the last 4-5 years should do it.

Comment: Wouldn't an easier task be to get Lion or Mountain Lion work on your hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is Xcode 4.5 on your mac.

The original post says how to run ios 5.1sdk on "Xcode 4.2 on Snow leopard".

Xcode 4.5 is not available on snowleopard.

Install Xcode 4.2 and follow the steps again.

Comment: Okay I think maybe my original post was a bit incorrect. I am actually running the iOS6 SDK but with XCode 4.2. Either way, that doesn't update the Simulator, which is what I really need at this point.

Comment: so basically there is still no answer how to run Xcode 4.2 and iPhone 5 simulator... ?

Comment: @raistlin I never found a way to accomplish this. My cheapest solution was to purchase a 4" iPod Touch.

Answer (score 0):

It's said that Xcode 4.2 is the last supported version on Snow Leopard. So no it won't work and you'll have to get Lion.
I found the answer on another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203444/xcode-4-5-with-ios-6-on-snow-leopard)

> You would have to be under Lion in this case with both Xcode 4.2 and
>   4.5 installed. There should be no problem with this.

---

**Don't forget...**

1. As stated in a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508357/import-ios-6-sdk-into-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)

   - "I installed Xcode 4.2 on a Snow Leopard and when iOS SDK was published I imported the iOS 5.1 SDK" Look at another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)
   - Use the 2nd post link. It works perfectly, just copy "6.0" instead of "5.1".
2. Don't forget that you could just use an external iOS device that can run [iOS6](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/)
3. You could always ask for support from [developer.apple technical support](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#techSupport)
4. Delete your simulator and re-download

Comment: 1. Yes I have the Mac App Store, not sure what that will resolve. I can't install Mountain Lion on my computer, thus I can't install the current XCode/iOS Simulator.

Comment: 2. I have the 6.0 SDK Installed and can load to 6.0 devices. My problem is with the iOS Simulator. I tried running the script from @StanSieler's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508357/import-ios-6-sdk-into-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard , but it did not change anything.

Comment: FYI, `backticks` are not meant for highlighting keywords and proper nouns. They're meant for highlighting code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use Virtual Box and run XCode in it. Of course, running OS X on virtual box is quite difficult and not entirely legal (although you do have a Mac, so it can be justified). You can follow this link if interested.

http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-on-virtualbox-with-windows-7-and-intel-pc

It's for windows 7, but you should be able to get it to work on OS X as well.

Answer (score 0):

I VMware Fusion 5 (and maybe 4 also, I don't remember) allows Mac OS X Lion and Mountain Lion to run in a VM. So you could install VMware Fusion, and use it to run a virtualized instance of Mountain Lion. Since the hardware is virtualized, it shouldn't matter that your Mac doesn't support anything newer than Snow Leopard.

Performance will likely be poor, though - my experience is that you need at *least* 4 gigs of RAM for VMware Fusion to run smoothly.  If your Mac is too old for Lion and Moutain Lion, it'll probably won't have that amount of RAM installed.