# How to run iPhone 5 Simulator under Xcode 4.2 and Snow Leopard?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-snow-leopard, iphone-5

I'm trying to figure it out how to get simulator for 4" screen. I've found questions here on SO about importing SDKs for newer iOS SDK ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613565/is-it-possible-to-get-the-ios-5-1-sdk-for-xcode-4-2-on-snow-leopard)) but I cannot get the simulator from iOS6 to get working under Xcode 4.2 and Snow Leopard. It made impossible to open any Storyboard and running any app (no difference if old app from iOS 4.2 or newer from iOS 5.1) wasn't even an option.
I read this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602789/running-iphone-5-simulator-on-snow-leopard) but it seems that answer was accepted even it does not tell anything usefull. Upgrading to Lion and running Xcode 4.5 etc - I know it is the best solution, but now it's out of reach and buying new mac isn't possible. Anybody?

Comment: no need buy new mac just upgrade current OS in your mac

Comment: I think you ned to buy a latest Mac, if your machine have the required capabilities then you can just upgrade the OS

Answer (score 0):

simply go to Xcode preference ---> select  Downloads and select Components tab .
Here you'll find  list of simulator that are installed and to be install. Install whatever you want to.

Comment: all I have is this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/d3rq.png/ and don't see how to import newer simulators. Should it be already there or should I import something?