# Running XCode 4.5 with iOS 6.xx on Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm running on XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 on Snow Leopard using iMac Early 2006 (Intel Core Duo 32bit). I'm waiting for iMac Late 2012 27 inch to arrive while I wanted to be ready with my app. At the same time, I wanted to move to iOS 6.xx SDK with XCode 4.5 on Snow Leopard. I have been reading some of the posts on this combination on Snow Leopard. My questions are:

1. Is the fix to use XCode 4.5 with iOS 6.xx on Snow Leopard really working for people?
2. I read that you can't use the iOS 6 simulator on a 32 bit iMac. Is this true?. If it is, is my only option to test the app on the device?
3. Can XCode 4.2 and XCode 4.5 co-exist or is it going to be a upgrade from 4.2 to 4.5?

Please advise.

Comment: Related: [Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6 on Snow Leopard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203444/xcode-4-5-with-ios-6-on-snow-leopard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding two versions of Xcode co-existing, here is a thread that addresses that (with the note that it's an older thread so there may be some differences for App Store Xcode vs. downloaded Xcode): [Can I have multiple xcode versions installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed)

In my own experience/research while I was on Snow Leopard, I did not find any positive results regarding running Xcode 4.5 or iOS6. I stuck with 4.2 and temporarily ran 4.5 on a separate Lion machine until I was able to upgrade. I also had no success using my iOS6 device for testing while connected to Xcode 4.2 (a message to the effect of "no device with compatible OS"), so I had to connect the device to the separate Lion machine as well.

If your new iMac is already on the way, I think you'll save a lot of headaches just holding out for that rather than trying to jury-rig the Snow Leopard machine. Once I updated to Mountain Lion, the transition from 4.2 to 4.5 for my project was very quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I wish Apple accelerates production of the newer iMacs. I might get it in by the end of Feb or early March. Until then, I wanted to see if I can try installing 4.5 with iOS 6 on Snow leopard (32 bit iMac)

Comment: I saw a similar question and a reply tells it is doable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621481/iphone-with-ios-6-and-xcode-4-2-issue

Comment: Ouch, I didn't realize the delay was that long right now. Regarding the linked post, it sounds like that will get you the iOS6 ability, but just to be clear you understand that it will not get you Xcode 4.5. The Xcode 4.5 installer is just used to grab the iOS6 items so that you can install them into Xcode 4.2. Since this is a kludge, if you have a separate device available already running iOS6, I would recommend testing against that device before upgrading your primary one, just in case things don't work out as planned - downgrading to iOS5 is a whole 'nother issue.

Comment: If I make Xcode 4.2 work with iOS 6 by following the article, do you still think I need Xcode 4.5 to test it on my device?. I have iPhone 4S running on 6.0.1 and I haven't paid for the developer license yet. I wanted to first compile/make changes to my app targeting iOS 6 and up and then pay for the dev. license to test it on the device. Do you think of any impediments on this approach?. I'm really sick waiting for my new iMac.

Comment: I'm not sure. Although I'm on Xcode 4.5 now and am testing on an iOS6 device, I haven't done anything iOS6-specific in my app. As long as you're not making your code incompatible with iOS5 you can still test against that OS in the simulator, so worst case is that the iOS6 testing doesn't work for you, but you haven't lost anything. That other post had some debate as to whether the debugging was really working under 4.2/iOS6 or just acted like it was - just something to watch out for.